# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request.Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a webservice programmed in asp.net . I want to reach webservice from android application using SOAP(ksoap2) .

Here is my soap segment,

```
//Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
//Webservice URL - WSDL File location
private static String URL = "http://locationbasedapp.net/Service1.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
//SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";

public static String invokeListLocationsWS(String datetext, String webMethName) {
    String xmlDataSet = "";
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo datetextPI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Username
    datetextPI.setName("datetext");
    // Set Value
    datetextPI.setValue(datetext);
    // Set dataType
    datetextPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(datetextPI);

    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to  boolean variable variable

        xmlDataSet =response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        MapActivity.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    return xmlDataSet;
}
```

While I am debugging the code , I have an error as mentioned on the question title. The error is seen on the

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

line..

I think I can't get response from webservice. How Can I fix it ?

Webservice returns xml.InnerText. It's type String.

Please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not an .NET developer I've seen similar error codes before using `Java` and it always boils down to the `XML` being returned by the calling `web service` being invalid.

In my case what I tried was capturing the raw `XML` response and then attempting to parse it using a `XML` parsing library.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: thanks for reply.Firstly, I should get response from webservice. It returns Xml.Innertext and after I will parse it using XML parsing library in java

Comment: @DavidPostill I like this comment. May I use it for my own comments?